# Writing to a random access file

Tags: java, file, streamwriter

I have a project in which I have to write to a random access file.

I am reading a country with a some information including: id, name, year of independence, etc. That information is what I have to write to the file.

My questions are:

- How can I measure the size of the record I'm writing to on the random access file? 
  I know how to do it via: `filewrite.int(variable)`. But the project requires me to somehow have a constant size of where I write each character.
- I know 2 bytes is one character, but how can I say "I want to write this line (where each line is a country with its information) so write the line from byte 1 to byte 15 and have a constant size"?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a sample file or change you make the sizes anything you want? What is the type of the id, the name or the year of independence or is that your choice too? BTW: You don't have to use two bytes for a character if you are using ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to measure the size of a record.  In this instance, I'd say you should define a fixed length for each field of a record.  This way, you will always know how long a record will be.  You should be able to use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Read through the documentation on that class. If you want to make your life easier, write a service class for your particular file to wrap the RandomAccessFile methods.

An example of a method signature for the service class would be:

```
void writeCountry(int recordNumber, String country) throws IllegalArgumentException;
```

Then when you implement this, you will do some math to figure out where to seek to, and what to write to file.

Comment: There is a small issue, and that is if country.length() exceeds the maximum size for that field.

Comment: That is where the IllegalArgumentException comes in.  You should throw that exception if the supplied length exceeds what you specify as the max length.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a fixed length for each field. Then format your values before writing them out.  Since each line is a fixed number of characters you can determine the number of bytes based on the number of lines.

You could use the Formatter class to help.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Specifically take a look at the Width and Precision sections of the doc.

Take a look at the out put of something like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(System.out);
    formatter.format("%5.5s %3.3s %3.3s %3.3s", "012345678901", "b", "c", "d");
}
```

Keep in mind what should happen if the value is larger than the field.

Answer (score -1):

[Read more at Ankit.co](http://ankit.co/tutorials/java-tutorials/input-output/random-access-file-java)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class RandomAccessDemo 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    try
    {       
      RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("test.txt", "rw");
      raf.writeInt(10);
      raf.writeInt(20);
      raf.writeInt(30);
      raf.writeInt(400);

      raf.seek((3 - 1) * 4);  // For 3rd integer, We are doing 2 * size of Int(4).

      raf.writeInt(99);

      raf.seek(0);   // Going back to start point

      int i = 0;
      while(raf.length()>raf.getFilePointer()) 
      {
        i = raf.readInt();
        System.out.println(i);
      }
      raf.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

View my post on Random Access Files in Java at [ankit.co](http://ankit.co)